# Is it possible run the ssis on the server?

Tags: ssis

---

I'm beginner in `ssis` ,install this software on my client `pc` in my company:
[image]

my question is this,can i install that software on the server and my employee work with that software remotly?thanks all.

Comment: If that is SSIS 2012 or later, you deploy it to the SSIS catalog then it runs on that server.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid can i edit the ssis package after edit?

Comment: You edit the SSIS package as a dtsx file, then you deploy it. You continue to edit the same dtsx file and deploy. So yes you can edit it. First you need to set up the `SSIS Catalog` then you need to `deploy` to it.... those are two terms to search on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install SSIS on the server, and have the employee RDP (Remote) into the server and edit the package directly on the server. (Not preferred, unless the employee is trusted to work directly on the server.)

To deploy it for execution, you deploy it to the catalog under the Integration Services Catalog in SSMS from SSDT. (SSIS).